java.lang.NullPointerException on flutter in app purchase package?
I am trying to integrate in_app_purchase package into my flutter projects. I am using this package because I have my own backend server for verifying purchase. But after integrating I am getting one error. I try to search on the internet but not getting any similar issues, what I am facing. Please from this community help me.
Following is my code-
class SubscriptionPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SubscriptionPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SubscriptionPage> createState() => _SubscriptionPageState();
}

class _SubscriptionPageState extends State<SubscriptionPage> {
  final InAppPurchase _inAppPurchase = InAppPurchase.instance;
  late StreamSubscription<List<PurchaseDetails>> _subscription;

  //Product Listing
  static const List<String> _productIds = [
    'com.....subscription'
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    final Stream<List<PurchaseDetails>> purchaseUpdated =
        _inAppPurchase.purchaseStream;
    _subscription =
        purchaseUpdated.listen((List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) {
      if (mounted) {
        _listenToPurchaseUpdated(purchaseDetailsList, context);
      }
    }, onDone: () {
      _subscription.cancel();
    }, onError: (Object error) {
      if (mounted) {
        showSnackBar(context, 'Something went wrong', Severity.error);
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<Subscription> getProducts() async {
    final bool isAvailable = await _inAppPurchase.isAvailable();
    if (!isAvailable) {
      return Subscription(
        isAvailable: isAvailable,
        products: [],
        notFoundIds: [],
      );
    }
    final ProductDetailsResponse productDetailResponse =
        await _inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails(_productIds.toSet());

    if (productDetailResponse.error != null) {
      throw Exception(productDetailResponse.error!.message);
    }
    return Subscription(
      isAvailable: isAvailable,
      products: productDetailResponse.productDetails,
      notFoundIds: productDetailResponse.notFoundIDs,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var media = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const BasicAppBar(
        title: 'Subscription',
        isBack: true,
        level: '3',
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          //.....
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _listenToPurchaseUpdated(
      List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList, BuildContext context) async {
    for (final PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails in purchaseDetailsList) {
      if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.pending) {
        showSnackBar(
          context,
          'You are purchasing a subscription',
          Severity.success,
        );
      } else if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.error) {
        showSnackBar(
          context,
          'Your purchased failed!',
          Severity.error,
        );
      } else if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased) {
        showSnackBar(
          context,
          'Your purchase is successfully',
          Severity.success,
        );
      }
    }
  }
}

Now I am facing one error on my debug_console-
W/BillingLogger( 7906): Unable to log.
W/BillingLogger( 7906): java.lang.NullPointerException

Here is the full screenshot-
Click to see image
